# git push / git pull error. What's different on the remote?

Tags: git

I'm working in a team of 3 and we are not usually editing the same files. When I have changes to send, I commit and push. Usually this works.

Sometimes, however, we are in a race to push. If somebody pushes before I do, I get the failed push

```
$ git push
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
To git@gitlab.ku.edu:crmdaprojects/Ticket-631.git
 ! [rejected]        reports2016 -> reports2016 (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'git@gitlab.ku.edu:crmdaprojects/Ticket-631.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work 
that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another 
repository  pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the 
    remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' 
for details.
```

I'm the only one who has edited the files for which I have made commits. It would not harm the project if my changes went through.  I did not edit any of the files that the teammates have entered. Unfortunately, they changed something in an entirely different directory. Gosh, I wish my commit would go into the remote without distraction.

I understand that's not what git wants to do, however. So I follow the hints

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From gitlab.ku.edu:crmdaprojects/Ticket-631
04cb4c6..05b2c2f  reports2016 -> origin/reports2016
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
WI/R/import.R | 16 ++++++++++------
 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

That pull causes a merge, and the editor pops open and I'm asked for an explanation of why I caused a merge.  All I type is "I ran git pull and I have no idea what conflicts are being merged" because, from the inside of that vi session, I can't even tell what files git changed.  After I safe the commit message, then I see it simply edited one file, "import.R".

This file "import.R", is not one I work on. It was changed by a teammate over the weekend, he pushed before I had a chance to do it. The update is not harmful as far as I can see. The pull was not dangerous.

However, this work flow is inconvenient. Every time I want to push my part of this larger project, the push fails, and I have to pull and then try to understand what happened.  If I work, say, 8 hours per day, I waste 20 or 30 minutes trying to figure out why push fails or pulls cause merge errors.

I'd like to know if there is a less aggravating work flow. How do programmers keep their sanity when there are 10s of coders in a project and they make changes all the time? Is there a nice way to know if any of the files I am editing have been changed in the remote? If NOT, then I don't mind pulling and I just move on, as in the case above. I might like a quick view of what changes there were, but that's not my top priority right now. I care most about pulling changes in files I'm revising right now.

From the git manuals, I can see the long way around this is:

```
$ git fetch
$ git diff
```

Then I wade through some output.  Is there a better way to fit this into my daily work flow?

Answer (score 0):

I think your frustration stems from the fact that you're not quite used to git yet. Pulling and pushing should take around 30 seconds, usually less.

git doesn't care about whether or not you are touching the same file. In fact, *you* shouldn't care either. If someone changes a file in the project, it's very possible that they've just broken the code you're working on. Code isn't isolated to the file it's written in. You should typically always pull, build, test, push.

However, if a change *is* made in the same file on the same lines, you will get a real conflict, which you would need to resolve. If you don't want a merge commit every time you pull, you need to run the following to configure it globally:

```
git config --global --add merge.ff true
```

Or for the current pull:

```
git pull --ff-only
```

Which will stop merge commits from being created. However, git usually pre-fills the merge commit comment, so it's likely you can leave your configuration as-is, and simply hit 'okay' when merging (assuming there are no conflicts).

And finally, it's common for people to work on their own branches, and only merge back to dev/master when their feature is complete (that is, you only merge back once per feature, barring fixes, etc). That way you won't get conflicts or ever have to pull changes

Comment: Using `--ff-only` is fine, but it's not really accurate to say that it will *remove* merge commits. Instead, it will just refuse to *create* merge commits, making `git merge` fail instead when fast-forwarding is not possible. Not that any of this jargon helps the OP, alas. (I think it's better for new users to run separate `fetch` and then `rebase` sequences by default, and then to introduce them to pull-configured-to-rebase as a convenience shortcut; but this still requires that they learn about merging, since rebase involves cherry-pick, which can merge! Teaching is hard... :-) )

Comment: @torek You're absolutely right - that was bad phrasing on my behalf.. I was trying to say it would remove merge commits in the sense that they will be removed from the workflow (and not deleted retroactively). I agree with the point about fetch and rebase, however, though I think it would be better to point a user to a guide at that point, as it can get quite in-depth! :)